# Refactor Controllers PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, refactoring

I got a situation where I have a controller that is responsible to return Views with some data that need to show it, but this data should be displayed from multiples views.

Let's take an example (is not a real class but just for get the idea):

```
class UserMapController extends BaseController
{

    public function index($username)
    {
       $posts = Post::all();
       $userInfo = User::findByUsername(username);
       $otherData = Book::all();
       return View::make('user.profile',compact('posts','userInfo','otherData'));
    }

    public function albums($username)
    {
       $posts = Post::all();
       $userInfo = User::findByUsername(username);
       $otherData = Book::all();
       $album = Album::findByUsername($username);
       return View::make('user.albums',compact('posts','userInfo','otherData','username','album'));
    }

}
```

The default data in this case are `$posts`, `$userInfo`, `$otherData` and I may use it in other 10 methods that it will send it to the view.

I used `View Composer` in laravel, very helpful but in this case the problem is that I get the value from the url, so I cannot perform a clean and dynamically view composer (Correct me if i'm wrong).

How do you do this kind of refactor, that when you need new data to send to all those views will not painful to insert it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually setting these up in a `beforeFilter` or multiple is preferred, then you just set variables as instance variables instead and you may reuse them as you like.  You can get the parameters from the route by using `Route::parameter('nameOfParam')`.

[beforeFilter and controller filter docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters)

Example:

```
<?php


class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter("@posts");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index', ['posts' => $this->posts]);
    }

    protected function posts()
    {
        $this->posts = Post::all();
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks I didn't know this technique, but still I see it not much dynamically because, i still need to write the variables to pass in the `make` method of each views. Correct me if I'm wrong. Also another clarification is where you said to use `Route::parameter('nameOfParam')` is because using the `before` filter the parameters go as parameters of that method?

Comment: Your assertion about the need for Route::parameter() is correct.  As for removing the need to insert them into the view layer in each action, you *could* just use View::share() or just write a helper method in the controller to prepare a given view with the arguments loaded from the filter, then add additional view parameters after.  This would abstract the logic well and still allow modification.

Comment: What's the difference between `Route::parameter` and `Route::input`?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into view composers.  Basically what they do is bind some data to a view so that whenever you call a view, that data is automatically retrieved and added.  It will keep all this extra logic out of your controllers and you wouldn't have to worry about it anymore.

```
View::composer(array('user.profile','user.albums'), function($view)
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    $userInfo = User::findByUsername(username);
    $otherData = Book::all();
    $view->with(compact('posts', 'userInfo', 'otherData'));
});

View::composer('user.albums', function($view)
{
    $album = Album::findByUsername($username);
    $view->with(compact('album'));
});
```

I don't believe that there is any recommended or common practice on where to put these, but I prefer creating a new file for them and adding them to the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks! But what about if I need a parameter from the url? example i have `http://myapp.dev/username` and I need the username for get the results of same queries?

Comment: I haven't tried it with view composers, but you should be able to use `Route::parameter('username');` to grab the username parameter from the route.